# How to compare two dataframes and remove non common columns in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two df's and then remove the not common columns in one of the df. This is what i did so far

```
colnames(data3) %in% colnames(data2)

 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [37]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [49]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [61]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [73] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

My question is how to get rid of columns that correspond to "FALSE" in the data3?

Comment: `data3[colnames(data3) %in% colnames(data2)]` ?

Comment: If `x` is a vector/list and `L` is a logical vector of equal length, `x[L]` returns the subset of `x` where `L` is `TRUE`. This is very basic, perhaps you should look for some tutorials/intros to R.

Comment: I know this was easy but someone i couldn't get it. Anyway it work great

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `intersect`?